# Change a url via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, web

I had a website which url is http://www.testingmyweb.comli.com

In my website a had a folder TCWEB. My website is in this folder.

I want to map http://testingmyweb.comli.com/TCWEB/home.html to http://testingmyweb.comli.com/

What can I changes do in `.htaccess` file?

Comment: note that `www.testingmyweb.comli.com` is not always equal to `testingmyweb.comli.com`, depends on your web server settings

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I think it was the other way around in the original post. But I am not sure.

Comment: My htaccess file coding is given below.
    # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working
RewriteBase /



RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Redirect /TCWEB/home.html  http://testingmyweb.comli.com/
What can I do to make a url like that http://testingmyweb.comli.com/

Comment: can you edit the question & put the update into it ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, your htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

Redirect /TCWEB/home.html testingmyweb.comli.com
```

The rule that you have appends `.html` to requests that are for html files (but don't have the extension). The redirect that you have underneath that needs to be removed. In order for you to rewrite `/` to `/TCWEB/home.html`, that mod_alias directive will cause a loop. Replace it with these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^$ /TCWEB/home.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /TCWEB/home.html
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

The first rule makes it so requests for `/` maps to `/TCWEB/home.html`, but the URL in the browser's address bar remains `http://www.testingmyweb.comli.com`. The second rule does what the `Redirect` does, except it checks that the request was actually made for `/TCWEB/home.html`, and not an internally rewritten URI. So when someone goes directly to `/TCWEB/home.html`, they get redirected to `/`, then the first rule gets applied.

Comment: Friends I write both code but it does not work. # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working RewriteBase / Now my file look like this.what did I do

Comment: @user1925876 You see your original htaccess file above? Remove the `Redirect` line and replace it with the bottom greyed out stuff.